# Set Gateway for our LAN

Tags: network, routing

I am new to Networking. In our organization we try to setup gateway for security purpose so that we can block certain harmful websites. All I know is gateway is a device. What we have is the LAN setup, Mikrotik router (to assign static IP for every computer in our company).

The details I know is default Gateway, subnetmask and assigned IP address for our company.

I want to know how can I achieve these requirement with gateway. we ready to have a CPU for this process with UNIX/LINUX OS. I guess I can access the gateway from this installed OS, but I don't know how to do this?

Simply, my requirement is achieve security in gateway level, what else I can do with gateway and how to use it.

I hope I can able describe what I want, please let me know If you guys don't understand.

Comment: Please tell me your organization isn't a bank.

Comment: No my organization is not bank

Answer (score 1):

To secure the gateway, you need a UTM/NGFW. A UTM (Unified Threat Management) box will provide you with the features you are looking for. By sending all traffic through the UTM, you will be able to control/sanitize the traffic. Try the free [SOPHOS](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-utm-home-edition.aspx) UTM to get an idea on what you will be able to achieve.